# IsImageUrl extension method written in F#

Tags: image, f#, url

I'm a newbie to F# and so I've written a [small extension method library](https://github.com/m4bwav/IsImageUrlDotNet) to practice the language.  The extension method attempts to determine if a url string is for an image.  I wrote the code as an extension method so that it can be used as an extension or static method in other .net languages, namely C#.

The code first checks the url's extension to see if a guess can be made about its content.  If no guess can be made, then the image is requested and the content type in the response's header is checked.

Any advice, refactorings, or criticisms welcome.
Thanks!

```
namespace IsImageUrlDotNet
open System.Net
open System
open System.IO


[<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>]
module IsImageUrlDotNetLib =   
    let ImageFileExtensions = ["png"; "jpg"; "gif"; "raw";"bmp"; "svg"; "jpeg"; "psd";]
    let NonImageFileExtensions = ["exe"; "pdf"; "html"; "htm"; "txt"; "mp3"; "wav"; "odp";]

    let private hasAFileExtensionInList(fileExtensionList:string list) (url:string) =
      if Path.HasExtension url = false then
         false
      else  
         let urlSplitList = url.ToLower().Split '.'
         let lastExtension = urlSplitList.[urlSplitList.Length - 1]
         List.contains lastExtension fileExtensionList

    let private hasAnImageFileExtension(url:string) =
      hasAFileExtensionInList ImageFileExtensions url

    let private hasAnNonImageFileExtension(url:string) =
      hasAFileExtensionInList NonImageFileExtensions url

    let private requestUrlAndCheckIfImage(url:string) =
        let req = WebRequest.Create(Uri(url)) 
        use resp = req.GetResponse() 
        let contentType = resp.ContentType
        if contentType.Contains("text/html") then
           false
        else
            contentType.Contains("image")

    [<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>]   
    let IsImageUrl(opt:string) =                
      match opt with
        | null | "" -> false
        | url when Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) = false -> false
        | url when hasAnImageFileExtension url -> true 
        | url when hasAnNonImageFileExtension url -> false 
        | _ -> requestUrlAndCheckIfImage opt
```

Sample Test (C#):

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldBeAbleToIdentifyACommonImageUrl()
{
    const string CommonImageUrl = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";

    var isImage = CommonImageUrl.IsImageUrl();

    Assert.IsTrue(isImage);
}
```

Comment: There is a fair amount of duplication in the first two functions that you could avoid without too much work

Comment: @JohnPalmer - Good idea, thanks, I updated the code likewise.

Comment: `ImageFileExtensions` includes "gif" and "raw" twice each, but is missing "jpeg". Also, it might be worth doing a performance comparison between `List.contains` and `Set.contains` for this use case.

Comment: `hasAFileExtensionInList` has a single parameter that is a tuple. A more idiomatic F# solution would be to define it with two parameters, most-significant parameter last: `let private hasAFileExtensionInList  (fileExtensionList:string list) (url:string) =...`. This is because it allows for partial function application in the definition of the follow-on functions: `let hasAnImageFileExtension = hasAFileExtensionInList ImageFileExtensions`

Comment: @JoelMueller- Thanks for the bug catch and the advice, I'll try to see if can implement your suggestion.

Comment: I updated based on your suggestions, thanks again!

Comment: Sorry for being a bit late, but I wrote an answer.
I'm not sure that you want to get in some input values. I would like to clarify some details to improve my answer. I not found a special place for easier communication. If you don't mind, I would like to continue in [SO chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f).

Answer (score 2):

1.
F# has a good system of type inference. You don't need to specify the type explicitly, the compiler in many cases will do it for you.
You can read more about it [here](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/type-inference/).

2.
As @JoelMueller said in comment, F# there's such an amazing opportunity as partial application.

> The idea of partial application is that if you fix the first N
>   parameters of the function, you get a function of the remaining
>   parameters

Taken from [Partial application](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/partial-application/)

So, you can rewrite the functions `hasAnImageFileExtension`, `hasAnNonImageFileExtension`:

```
let private hasAnImageFileExtension =
  hasAFileExtensionInList ImageFileExtensions 

let private hasAnNonImageFileExtension =
  hasAFileExtensionInList NonImageFileExtensions
```

3.
Several very small comments:

a) In `hasAFileExtensionInList` instead `urlSplitList.[urlSplitList.Length - 1]` you can use [Seq.last](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.last%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D)

b) for me, construction like:

```
if Path.HasExtension url = false then
         false
      else ...
```

better, rerwite as:

```
  if Path.HasExtension url then
     ...
  else  
     false
```

4.
In function `IsImageUrl` it is better to use `if-then-else` instead pattern matching

5.
Question.

Why not use [Path.GetExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

When string not valid will throw the exception. It is better to provide this option.

---

I don't post a new version of the code, as I plan to edit the answer.

---

Comment: Nice comments, thanks for the review.  I'll try to remember to review and update the code hopefully later today.